# error by uploading 200mb file to google cloud bucket

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload 200mb file to google cloud bucket. I wrote script using this code sample:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/crud_object.py

on macos everything is working, but when my colleague trying this script on windows, he get such error:

ssl.SSLWantWriteError: The operation did not complete.

It happens only with big files (200mb), 20mb file were uploaded successfully. So maybe anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the library you're using isn't well maintained. Would it be possible for you to switch to the [google-cloud-storage library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-storage)?

Mike

Comment: yes, i switched to this library and it worked! Thank you